# Можно ли использовать map для итераций по объекту?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли использовать map для итераций по объекту?

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так

```js
const objectTest = {
  foo: 'boo',
  too: 'woo',
};

Object.entries(objectTest)
  .map(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))
```

Answer (score 3):

мы в компании часто пользуемся:

```
const testObject = { a: 'b', c: 'd' };
Object.keys(testObject).map(key => console.log(key, testObject[key]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1(Map):

```
Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key, index) {
   console.log(myObject[key]);
});

console.log(myObject);
```

Вариант 2(Map):

```
let newObj = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({[k]: obj[k]})));
```

Так же можно написать свой:

```
Object.map = function(o, f, ctx) {
    ctx = ctx || this;
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
        result[k] = f.call(ctx, o[k], k, o); 
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: только map интересует, спасибо

Comment: Убрал остальные, и добавил несколько вариантов с **map** Спасибо за поправку!

Comment: Модифицировать Object.map не круто